# How to cleanup celery_taskmeta?

Tags: task, celery, django-celery

I've been reading django-celery to try to find a native way of cleaning up celery_taskmeta, so this table won't grow up too much when in production environment.

Can'f find nothing. Should i do a command to deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a cronjob running a Django command that executes this SQL statement:

```
"truncate table celery_taskmeta"
```

deleted 50.000 records in 0.47ms.

Answer (score 6):

*I'm not using django-celery so my answer could be incomplete.*

There is a method in the Backend that allow you to force cleanup of celery_taskmeta : in celery.backends.base.BaseBackend, you can find method cleanup()

So, when I need to force cleanup I have 3 ways :

1. using the AsyncResult on producer side
2. using the task on the consumer side
3. celerybeat task

### on producer side

```
# Launch a task
my_task = add_a_task() # use the Task.delay() method for example
# my_task is a celery.result.AsyncResult instance
# Retrieve backend and call cleanup
my_task.backend.cleanup()
```

### on the consumer side

```
from celery import Task
from .celery_app import my_celery_app

# Class for a task
@my_celery_app.task()
class CopyTask(Task):
    # A Task instance got a backend property

    def run(self,**kwargs):
        """ Running method of the task """
        # Do something
        pass

    def force_cleanup(self):
        """ Force cleanup. """
       self.backend.cleanup()
```

Note that calling a cleanup in the task itself seems quiet awfull.

### with celerybeat task

A third option, is using a celerybeat task that cleanup backend celery_taskmeta.
This is the one I probably choose.

celery beat is basically a scheduler and you can run the task you want.
So you can have a dedicated task, like this one :

```
from celery import Task
from .celery_app import my_celery_app

# Class for a task
@my_celery_app.task()
class CleanupTask(Task):
    # A Task instance got a backend property

    def run(self,**kwargs):
        """ Running method of the task """
        # Cleanup here
        self.backend.cleanup()
```

Setting a celery beat, like a crontab job [is well documented](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I used your celery beat solution to clean up my result backed for a django app.